# How directory structure for Web project (html + css + js + java/spring) should look with javascript Jasmine unit tests?

Tags: java, javascript, css, html, unit-testing

I am trying to incorporate into my project some Jasmine javascript unit tests. Where should I put it in the source tree? This is my current structure:

```
projectName/
  css/
  img/
  js/
  index.html (etc)
```

It should be in this public directory, or outside of it? I will be incorporating this frontend part into a Java Spring project. What should whole structure should look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a similar fashion that you have your java unit tests set up.
If you have a source folder at the root of your project and then a test folder with the same package layout and classes that serve as tests, do that same thing at the root of your web project: js_test, jsTest ...

The question you're asking unfortunately has no standard. At this point it is up to the developer to decide the layout of his/her own project.

In industry this actually has its own benefits (perhaps in terms of propriety) but at the end of the day a different team or developer may have a different layout than another developer even among his/her own projects.